# Covert time based string to number

Tags: python, sql, .net, azure, etl

I have 2 fields in a SQL table:
1: today's date
2: time estimate

Time estimate is natural language so it can be any string variation: tomorrow, a date, in a few days, a date range etc. I need to convert the time estimate string into a day/time numeric value. E.g, in a few days is 3.

Comment: Can you provide some code or sample data? And code that you have already tried?

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/alvinwan/timefhuman

Comment: Else you would to build a NLP algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You could use the date command on linux, though you would need to make some minor adjustments.

For example, tommorrow (not case sensitive by the way):

```
date -d tommorrow
```

and in python:

```
estimate = "tommorrow"
date = os.popen(f'date -d {estimate}').read()
```

The "in a few days" option is too ambiguous to be converted to a date right away though, so you could make in a few days to be a "+3days" parameter for the date command.